# How deal with the parameter 'error' in a call back function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

what is the real purpose of the error parameter in a call back function?

I've done many node.js courses, and the parameter error always appears in the same way:

```
something(function(error, result) {
  if(error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
   // do something with the result.
  }
});
```

This is it? I should always use a console.log(error) if the error is true? I should not send a message to the views?

Can someone show me a good example of dealing with the error parameter in a call back function??

Comment: If the `error` parameter is non-null, then that means that whatever it is that you attempted to do failed for some reason. You shouldn't ignore it.

Comment: Just to build on @Pointy's comment, the error messages will be system errors that you probably won't want your users to see, mainly because you want to keep that part of the application opaque to them. If you're talking about, say, authentication errors like "password not recognised", then those errors will tend to be in the response instead, and those you should add to the view. Maybe set up an admin email account and have the app send you the system errors to that instead. I maybe wrong about some/all of this, but this has been my limited experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult do describe what to do with the error as it depends on what `something` is.

To give you a view how it works please consider this asynchronous pattern:

```
something(function(error, result){
    if(error) {
        //exception handler
    } else {
        //normal execution flow
    }
});
```

as equivalent of synchronous pattern:

```
try {
    var result = something();
    //normal execution flow
} catch (error) {
    //exception handler
}
```

So you should do the same thing with the `error` as you would normally do in `catch` block.